# Laravel Eloquent upsert method does not recognise UUID primary key and generates insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, upsert

I'm working on the project with the following code:

##### Schema

```php
Schema::create('form_pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->foreignUuid('form_id')
        ->index()
        ->constrained()
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('sort');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

##### Model

```php
class FormPage extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use HasUuids;
    
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'form_id',
        'name',
        'sort',
    ];

    // ...
}
```

##### Eloquent upsert

```php
FormPage::upsert(
    [
        [
            "id" => "23456693-9011-3c27-9556-408044349520",
            "sort" => 0,
        ],
        [
            "id" => "66accb28-aff2-3f4c-9006-7de7a6512e30",
            "sort" => 2,
        ],
        [
            "id" => "b1964720-e475-3733-898b-d4084863dd24",
            "sort" => 1,
        ],
    ],
    ['id'],
    ['sort'],
);
```

The records already exist in the database and the only thing that changes is the value of the `sort` column, but eloquent doesn't seem to recognise them and throws the following error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: form_pages.name (Connection: sqlite, SQL: insert into "form_pages" ("created_at", "form_id", "id", "sort", "updated_at") values (2023-05-24 17:11:35, b1681611-ea6b-3e91-afc1-f45458a95552, 83e4ff46-eb0a-3587-ba75-832635c242b4, 0, 2023-05-24 17:11:35), (2023-05-24 17:11:35, b1681611-ea6b-3e91-afc1-f45458a95552, 30c09d4d-7418-31d7-ac1e-5371bcf12f67, 2, 2023-05-24 17:11:35), (2023-05-24 17:11:35, b1681611-ea6b-3e91-afc1-f45458a95552, 26eaa72b-ac62-3c54-aee9-7c0faf7392ce, 1, 2023-05-24 17:11:35) on conflict ("id") do update set "sort" = "excluded"."sort", "updated_at" = "excluded"."updated_at")

According to [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#upserts):

> All databases except SQL Server require the columns in the second argument of the upsert method to have a "primary" or "unique" index. In addition, the MySQL database driver ignores the second argument of the upsert method and always uses the "primary" and "unique" indexes of the table to detect existing records.

I'm running this on MySQL 8, but perhaps there is something I missed - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I do not think this would be the issue, but I am assuming that `use HasUuids` is setting `keyType = string` and `autoincrement = false`, right?

Comment: Thanks @matiaslauriti - no that's not it - I've just figured it out - will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears I've forgotten that during the `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement, if you have any of the columns set as `NOT NULL` - you have to provide the value for them in the first argument (yep, error message says it loud enough). After refactoring my code and adding the mandatory `name` index the `upsert` statement now looks as follow

```php
FormPage::upsert(
    [
        [
            "id" => "23456693-9011-3c27-9556-408044349520",
            'name' => 'Page 1',
            "sort" => 0,
        ],
        [
            "id" => "66accb28-aff2-3f4c-9006-7de7a6512e30",
            'name' => 'Page 2',
            "sort" => 2,
        ],
        [
            "id" => "b1964720-e475-3733-898b-d4084863dd24",
            'name' => 'Page 3',
            "sort" => 1,
        ],
    ],
    'id',
    ['sort'],
);
```